# if else and if else not working in ansible template

Tags: ansible, django-templates

I am checking for pushing data based upon variables set true or false.
My varaibles file which is json file has
{
`"isfs" : True`
}

and my template (t2.j2)has below condition

```
{% if  '{ isfs | d() | bool }' -%} 
  <perform operation >
{% else -%}
  <perform 2 operation
```

Every time it executes `<perform opertaion >`even if change value of json file `"isfs": False`.

Please pour some suggestion.

I tried d(true) and also I tried with elif condition nothing helping me

Comment: `{% if isfs -%}` for now what you are doing is `if 'string that is not empty'` which always resolve in a truthy value.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply how tp avoid that ,myy requirement based upon the variable

Comment: i tried if isfs == false

Answer (score 0):

just test the variable. This shoud do what you want. Any True or true value is supposed to return true.

```
{% if isfs %}
```

cast if needed:

```
{% if isfs | bool %}
```

**edit: I think i misunderstood that you are evaluating against a json file that contains '{ "isfs" : True }'. You'll need to parse the json file to get the value. Considering the json file content is in the json_file variable:**

```
{% if json_file.isfs %}
```

Comment: ... and default as well if needed `{% if isfs | default(false) | bool %}`

Comment: Thanks you so much ,but unfortunately  its not getting first loop ```{% if isfs | default(false) | bool %}```

Comment: If i use ```{% if isfs %} `` it sayas isfs undefined variable

Comment: then check if variable is defined:
{% if isfs is defined and isfs %}